# Getting the user's id sent to them via email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, webforms

I am able to send to a user email after submitting their data into sql database getting some information from the form they filled. I achieve this with an HTML template with placeholders, then replacing them according in my codebehind in asp.net using C#. But I have tried to ensure that also i sent to them their Application No that is uniquely generated in Microsoft SQL Server Datatabase. For example Application No: CHV1800000001 this is uniquely created and i want to email them to each user after submitting their form. Please help out.

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/Account/RegMessage.html")))
        {

            MailText = reader.ReadToEnd();



            //Repalce [userdetails] = user details  
           // MailText = MailText.Replace("[ApplicationID]", reg.ApplicationID.ToString());
            MailText = MailText.Replace("[FirstName]", txtFN.Text.Trim());
            MailText = MailText.Replace("[Surname]", txtLN.Text.Trim());
            MailText = MailText.Replace("[MatricNo]", txtmatric.Text.Trim());
            MailText = MailText.Replace("[DateApplied]", txtdap.Text.Trim());



            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.To.Add(txtemail.Text.ToString());
            MailAddress from = new MailAddress("scholarships@optimumresourcesmgt-ng.com", "CHEVRON Scholarships");
            msg.From = from;
            msg.Subject = "Successful Application Confirmation";
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            //BuildEmailMsg();

            msg.Body = MailText;
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.1and1.com", 587);
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("scholarships@optimumresourcesmgt-ng.com", "Optimuma@123");
            smtpClient.Send(msg);
            InsertRegistration();
            lblMessage.Visible = true;
            lblMessage.Text = "Application successfully submitted. We will email your Applicaion details to you. Please check your email both spam and inbox folders.";
            lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            //End of Send Mail Region
```

Thanks

Comment: Get the value from SQL and then include it in the email you are sending?

Comment: This has nothing to do with javascript. Please tag questions according to specific problem

Comment: @charlietfl thanks.. I will take corrections. Please any guide or example?

Comment: When you are loading the form, you should also render the applicationId in a hidden server control and then get the value from the hidden control when you want to send the email.

Comment: Other thing you can do is get the applicationId from the database and include it in the email before you send email.

Comment: Thanks! The form is to be filled by the users. The applicationid is generated once they submit their form. I want a situation whereby after submitting their form the applicationid is also sent to them together with other values entered by them in the textbox controls in asp.net using c#. I am getting the other values easily but since the applicationid is gotten after form submission and not before that is my challenge now. I have used output in my insert statement to get the last inserted applicationid but i am at a cross road how to called it up in when building my mail in C#

Answer (score 0):

Are you incrementing the unique via SQL IDENTITY?

If yes then you can use scope_identity to fetch the value along with insert statement.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I have used scope_identity or OUTPUT Inserted.ApplicationID to fetch the value along with the insert statement. How do build it into my mail and send out to each user after clicking on the submit button?

Comment: thank you. I appreciate. Please can you give me a sample mail set up fetching a users id that is auto-generated?

Comment: SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(...);
con.Open();

string query = "insert into Users (Name, Message, Phone) values ('Joe', 'Demo', '12345'); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

int userID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

Use this variable to append with the email body.

Comment: You are wonderful man! you mean the variable: int UserID=Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); or all of them: You can find my email body in my first question. I am using an html template.

Comment: int UserID=Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); only This line. It will give you the id you can use same concept for your applicationid

Comment: my applicationid is a varchar datatype of computed column.

Comment: This is my mail section: //Repalce [userdetails] = user details  
            //MailText = MailText.Replace("[ApplicationID]", reg.ApplicationID.ToString();
            MailText = MailText.Replace("[FirstName]", txtFN.Text.Trim());
            MailText = MailText.Replace("[Surname]", txtLN.Text.Trim());
            MailText = MailText.Replace("[MatricNo]", txtmatric.Text.Trim());
            MailText = MailText.Replace("[DateApplied]", txtdap.Text.Trim());  How do i bring that variable in here? I am replacing the placeholders in my html email template. All others are working.

Comment: I would suggest to add one column to you table named RecordID with int datatype and set identity property for that to true, post that write a query SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(...);
con.Open();

string query = "insert into youtable (the required columns) values (specific values); SELECT TOP 1 ApplicationID from tablename order by RecordID desc;";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

String applicationID =cmd.ExecuteScalar();

Use this variable to append application id with the email body.

Comment: You have really tried in guiding me through. I should put the whole block or only: SELECT TOP 1 ApplicationID from tablename order by RecordID desc;"; SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con); String applicationID =cmd.ExecuteScalar(); or SELECT TOP 1 ApplicationID from tablename order by RecordID desc;"; SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con); String applicationID =cmd.ExecuteScalar(); Also, sir. seeing the format above i used in replacing placeholders. Can i get a sample of how to call it up in the order above?